# Please, Explain this regex expression in detail (Powershell)

Tags: regex, powershell

i have seen this powershell code on a [Code Golf Challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19138/strip-all-non-printable-ascii-characters) to remove all non printable characters:

`$text -replace "[^ -x7e]",""`

Is supposed to do the same as this:

`$text -replace "[^ \x21-\x7E]",""`

I understand what makes the second expression, but not how first expression can make the same.

My question is: ¿Why first expression has nothing before the dash? (What does it mean?) and ¿Why don't have a backslash before x7E?

Can someone explain in detail the first expression? Thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you both, all was the space! 

And I was going crazy, lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^ -x7e]` is the same what `[^\x20-x7e]` is.
 And that's because space's unicode is 32. And 32 in Hexadecimall system is `20`.
So instead of using the space escape sequence You just use the space as it is.

And in `[^ \x21-x7e]` there is a space at the begining which means anything except for space or anything in range `\x21-x7e`.
 Which is quite redundant because You could just do `\x20-x7e`

Answer (score 1):

It has something before the dash. It has a space.

Remove the space and I expect it will not function the same way (it will likely be seen as four characters: dash, `x`, `7`, and `e` but I'm not sure).

The hex value for space is `x20`. So `[^ x21-x7e]` so you can extend the range down by one by removing the explicit `x21`.